# Undefined function or variable inside a for loop within a function (matlab)

Tags: matlab, undefined-variable

I write a function to compute the Kendall distance using a for-loop

```
function [ distance ] = kendall_tau(y, yy, pair_list)
distance = 0;
for row = 1:length(pair_list)
    i = pairlist(row,1);
    j = pairlist(row,2);
    if (y(i)<y(j))&&(yy(i)>yy(j)) || (y(i)>y(j))&&(yy(i)<yy(j))
       distance = distance + 1;
    end
end
```

When I try this function with real values this undefined variable keep raising and I dont know why

```
kendall_tau(y_valid,y_valid_shuffle,pair_list_valid)
```

y_valid, y_valid_shuffle is 150x1 matrix, pair_list_valid is 978x2 matrix

```
Undefined function or variable 'pairlist'.
Error in kendall_tau (line 17)
    i = pairlist(row,1);
```

I'm noob in matlab. Thank for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, most likely is that

```
i = pairlist(row,1);
```

should have been

```
i = pair_list(row,1);
```

A typo, and since MATLAB uses same () for accessing array element and giving function arguments, it gives an undefined function error.

Comment: Thank for your answer ! I just fix and it works. Well, this is really stupid of me not noticing it ...